# ORACLE SQL - Need query to return one row (ID exists multiple times)

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Picture of Data]

In need of some assistance... I've tried for awhile and can't get what I need. (it's going to be used as a sub query within the FROM statement of another query) that will return  the creator ID and 1 note. I only need ONE row returned per ID. (Can be any of the notes that matches the creator ID -- doesn't matter) The creator ID is a key that shows up multiple times in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by creator order by ordnum) as seqnum
      from notes t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```